# Interesting javascript quirks

Tags: javascript

I have this following if statement:

RG is "100" and max is "85"

```
if (RG == "" | RG > max) {
            //Doesn't execute
        }
```

Since RG isn't "" and RG is larger than max why isn't the code executing?  I believed the operator was short circuiting (hence only the one pipe |) but changing it didn't make any difference. My guess is that it is comparing literal strings - so how do I force javascript to treat them as floats?

Just to be clear I need both parts of the OR to be checked and only execute if either of them is true.

Comment: Why do you need the second part checked if the first one is already true?

Comment: I tried this in Firebug console and it worked for me, `var RG = 100, max=85;
if (RG == "" || RG > max) {
        console.log('Hello World!');
}` I would love to see what is wrong with your code, hopefully it has nothing to do with JS variable scope and I am missing something here.

Comment: @Kumar: `RG` and `max` are strings for some reason...

Comment: @Felix, I knew I am missing something, `var RG = "100", max="85";
if (RG == "" || +RG > +max) {
        console.log('Hello World!');
}` works! Thanx a ton for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believed the operator was short circuiting (hence only the one pipe |) but changing it didn't make any difference

I take it then it originally looked like this:

```
if (RG == "" || RG > max) {
    //Doesn't execute
}
```

We can ignore the first part because it's false, so your question is why wasn't `RG > max` true? And the answer is that "100" comes before "85" in the string collation order. Strings are not numbers, you don't compare them numerically.

If you want them to be floats as you said, you can make them numbers via `parseFloat` (or `parseInt` as they look like integers, but you said floats, so...):

```
if (RG == "" || parseFloat(RG) > parseFloat(max)) {
    //Doesn't execute
}
```

I've done it inline there, but the odds seem high you'll want to do it earlier and assign the result to variables, unless this really is the only place you'll use the values as numbers.

Comment: So I need to keep the || in there?

Comment: @m.edmondson: Yes. You don't want to be doing a bitwise operation. You're doing logical operations here.

Comment: @m.edmondson: Makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (RG === "" || parseFloat(RG) > parseFloat(max)) {
        // should execute
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `===` instead of `==` to check for the empty string, as explained in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423048/interesting-javascript-quirks/6423150#6423150).

Answer (score 1):

i prefer

```
if((!RG) || RG*1>max*1) 
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I force javascript to treat them as floats?

Like this:

```
var RG = "100",
    max = "85";

if (RG === "" || Number(RG) > Number(max)) {
  // Your code goes here.
  // It will be executed if RG is the empty string OR if RG > max.
}
```

`Number(foo)` will coerce `foo` into a number. You could also use `+foo` but I think this is more readable.

You should use `parseFloat` instead if the string can contain text as well.

Note that you need a strict equality check (`===`) when checking for the empty string, since `RG == ""` will be true if `RG` is `0`, `'0'`, `false`, etc. as well.

Answer (score 0):

well, parse the strings.

```
if (RG == "" | parseFloat(RG) > parseFloat(max)) {             
//Do Something    }
```